# Solving a differential-difference equation-number theory

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have the following set of differential-difference equations related to Buchstab iterations in number theory
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (s F(s))^{\prime}=f(s-1) \text { for } s>1 \\
& (s f(s))^{\prime}=F(s-1) \text { for } s>2
\end{aligned}
$$
with initial conditions $F(s)=\frac{2 e^\gamma}{s}$ for $1 \leq s \leq 3, f(s)=0$ for $1 \leq s \leq 2$, where $\gamma$ is a constant.

I want to show that the equations above are satisfied by
$$ 
F(s):=2 e^\gamma\left(\frac{1_{s>1}}{s}+\sum_{j \geq 3, \text { odd }} \frac{1}{j !} \int_{[1,+\infty)^{j-1}} 1_{t_1+\ldots t_{j-1} \leq s-1} \frac{d t_1 \ldots d t_{j-1}}{t_1 \ldots t_j}\right) $$
$$
f(s):=2 e^\gamma \sum_{j \geq 2, \text { even }} \frac{1}{j !} \int_{[1,+\infty)^{j-1}} 1_{t_1+\ldots +t_{j-1} \leq s-1} \frac{d t_1 \ldots d t_{j-1}}{t_1 \ldots t_j}
$$
with the convention that $t_j:=s-t_1-\cdots-t_{j-1}$.

I am struggling to see how I can differentiate when the indicator is under the integral. I have tried a Dirac delta approach, as well as a recursive argument but I didn't get anywhere. Any pointers would appreciated.